# WIF application instances behind load balancer

Tags: c#, asp.net, rsa, wif, adfs

I have many WIF application instances behind a load balancer that consumes claims from a STS. I used a RSA key container generated using aspnet_regiis.exe and added event handler as per this [link](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1898.aspx#Q1) to use RSA encryption to have a shared private key instead of default DPAPI encryption. I'm getting "The signature is not valid. The data may have been tampered with" error.

Any pointers will be helpful.

EDIT: Adding Identity Model section

```
   <microsoft.identityModel>
        <service>
            <audienceUris>
                <add value="https://mysite.com" />
            </audienceUris>
            <federatedAuthentication>
                <wsFederation passiveRedirectEnabled="false" https://mysts.com/sts" realm="https://mysite.com requireHttps="false" />
                <cookieHandler requireSsl="false" />
            </federatedAuthentication>
            <applicationService>
                <claimTypeRequired>
                    <claimType type="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name" optional="false" />
                    <claimType type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role" optional="false" />
                </claimTypeRequired>
            </applicationService>
            <issuerNameRegistry type="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.ConfigurationBasedIssuerNameRegistry, Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35">
                <trustedIssuers>
                    <add thumbprint="40A1D2622BFBDAC80A38858AD8001E094547369B" name="CN=IdentityTKStsCert" />
                </trustedIssuers>
            </issuerNameRegistry> 
        </service>
    </microsoft.identityModel>

void OnServiceConfigurationCreated(object sender, ServiceConfigurationCreatedEventArgs e)
{
    CspParameters cp = new CspParameters();
    cp.KeyContainerName = "MyRsaKey";
    RSACryptoServiceProvider rcsp = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(cp);
    List<CookieTransform> sessionTransforms =
        new List<CookieTransform>(new CookieTransform[] {
        new DeflateCookieTransform(),
        new RsaEncryptionCookieTransform(rcsp),
        new RsaSignatureCookieTransform(rcsp) });
    SessionSecurityTokenHandler sessionHandler = new SessionSecurityTokenHandler(sessionTransforms.AsReadOnly());
    e.ServiceConfiguration.SecurityTokenHandlers.AddOrReplace(sessionHandler);
}
```

Comment: Please add the web.config of your app.

Comment: @EugenioPace, are there any specific sections you would like to look at?

Comment: The identity model section (WIF).

Comment: Do you also have this? protected void Application_Start()
{
FederatedAuthentication.ServiceConfigurationCreated += this.OnServiceConfigurationCreated; 

...
}

Comment: Yes, I have that in Application_Start